# extend python function in odoo from another custom python?

Tags: python, odoo

how can i extend a python function from another py with params in same folder in framework odoo?. for example:

main.py

```
class account_invoice(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    def create(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
        get_xml = self._generate_xml(ids.xml)
```

library.py

```
class library_invoice(osv.osv):

    def _generate_xml(self,xml):
        build xml......
        return xml
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean monkeypatching?

Comment: not necessarily attempt to take native objects inherits from Odoo to handle variables in another .py and return it to the model of precedence. thnks in davance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend a python function in Odoo, you can do it by writing:

```
def _generate_xml(self,xml):
   get_xml = super(account_invoice, self)._generate_xml(xml)
   # And from now on you can add whatever you want...
```

**NOTE**

I've just realized that you are trying to extend the method in a class which does not inherit from `account.invoice`. To be honest, I've never tried to extend a function from a class which does not inherit from the class where the original method was declared. I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: yes, very similar to the method by which classes are extended between CSS and HTML;am trying to inherit native values from account.py to send objs to another library.py, to handle and return the values to account.py to continue with the normal flow in the views,greetings

Answer (score 0):

Finaly done

first, i need to load the file in the **init**.py

import main

import library #for exmaple

after, its able call the funcion anywhere main.py by self.pool.get like this

from library import library_invoice
var = self.pool.get('library.invoice')._generate_xml(param)